# Residue of a non-identically zero function

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Assume f(z)is analytic in the complex plane and let f be a complex function which is not identically zero.Then,show that 
Res(1/f(z^3),0)=0.

I know that the residue is calculating for only singularity points but here we don't have any. Could you please give a hint how to deal with this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you have singularities?  Whenever $f(z)=0$, you have a singularity.

Comment: Because of the assumption

Comment: $f$ is analytic, but $1/f$ might not be.  For example, consider the case where $f(z)=z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch: Consider the behavior of $f$ at $0$.  We can write $f(z)=z^k g(z)$ where $k$ is some nonnegative integer, $g$ is analytic, and $g(0)\not=0$.  Then
$$
\frac{1}{f(z^3)}=\frac{1}{z^{3k}g(z^3)}=\frac{1}{z^{3k}}\cdot\frac{1}{g(z^3)}.
$$
Since $g(0)\not=0$, $\frac{1}{g(z)}$ is an analytic function near $0$.  Therefore, $\frac{1}{g(z)}$ has a power series expansion at $0$.  In other words:
$$
\frac{1}{g(z)}=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+a_3z^3+\cdots.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{1}{g(z^3)}=a_0+a_1z^3+a_2z^6+a_3z^9+\cdots.
$$
Hence,
$$
\frac{1}{f(z^3)}=\frac{1}{z^{3k}}(a_0+a_1z^3+a_2z^6+a_3z^9+\cdots).
$$
The residue at $0$ is the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ in this power series expansion.  However, the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ is zero since the exponents are all multiples of $3$.